How to configure two cucumber runner files in jenkins file
As we know when any feature file failed we are storing in a text file. To run that failed.txt file we are using 2nd runner file. If we run second runner file it is executing the failed one only.
Is there any config set up in jenkins file after completion of first runner it will trigger second runner file to run failed one
Below is my 2 runner files
// Runner1.java
https://github.com/RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
features = "src/test/resources/features",
glue = "stepDefinitions",
tags = "https://github.com/Firstset",
plugin = {"pretty", "html:target/cucumber-reports", "rerun:target/rerun1.txt"}
)
public class Runner1 {
}

// RerunFailedTests1.java
https://github.com/RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
features = "@target/rerun1.txt",
glue = "stepDefinitions",
plugin = {"pretty", "html:target/cucumber-reports-rerun"}
)
public class RerunFailedTests1 {
}


I am new to jenkins. How can i configure my two runner files in jenkins file
How can we publish reports after these 2 runners complete

I am completly new to jenkins. I am running 2nd runner file to run failed one only
